# Using dynamic connection strings to connect to sybase via vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, odbc, sybase

I need you help to get the syntax for assigning the server, port and database name using parameters.
the script works perfectly fine if I pass the variable in the command explicitly.

Dim myConn1 As Odbc.OdbcConnection = New Odbc.OdbcConnection("Driver=Adaptive Server Enterprise;uid=XXX;server=**& SRVR &**;port=**& PRT &**;database=**& dbname &**;pwd=XXX")

Please advise me where am I going wrong.request for Your prompt assistance.
Thanks
Mayur

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually concatenating any strings.  How many double quotes are there in this:

```
"Driver=Adaptive Server Enterprise;uid=XXX;server=& SRVR &;port=& PRT &;database=& dbname &;pwd=XXX"
```

There are exactly two, which means that that whole thing is one string.  If you want to join multiple strings then there have to actually be multiple strings:

```
"Driver=Adaptive Server Enterprise;uid=XXX;server=" & SRVR & ";port=" & PRT & ";database=" & dbname & ";pwd=XXX"
```

You can avoid silly issues like this by not using string concatenation in the first place.  You could use `String.Format` or, in VB 2015, string interpolation to make things clearer or you could do what you're supposed to do when building a connection string from parts and use a connection string builder.  As you're building an ODBC connection string, you would use the OdbcConnectionStringBuilder class:

```
Dim builder As New OdbcConnectionStringBuilder("Driver=Adaptive Server Enterprise;uid=XXX;pwd=XXX")

builder("server") = server
builder("port") = port
builder("database") = database

Using connection As New OdbcConnection(builder.ConnectionString)
    '...
End Using
```